# Database schema for one-to-one and group chat

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

I am developing API's for chat application that has one-to-one and group chat based on invite. e.g I want to chat with someone first message that i am gonna send him will go as a invite after accepting invitation they can chat and add other users in chat [Group chat]. I am little conscious about minimum tables. The database that i am using now is not fulfilling  my needs. Here is image that shows my current DB. 
[image: Here is the current schema]
Suggest me some changes or any other options.

Thanks

Comment: Daisy this question is way too broad. We don't even know what you want your chat app to do.

Comment: It's basically a social app. Where people search for someone and and ask for chat by sending invitation. After that they can invite some other users in conversation or start a new group chat . It is only a text chat no audio/video or images are exchanged in between. Chat is a separate module whole application is complete just want this chat feature in best way as possible.

Comment: I think it is good. I would not have done it differently.

Comment: I know it has been a long time, but I'm interested to know why you've created two tables for thread (thread_user and thread)? Is one not going to suffice to link to the messages?

Comment: @Daishy the structure seems exactly the same as I have drawn for myself now. You're mentioning "not fulfilling your needs" however you're not mentioning what is the problem you have.
@PrahladYeri it's needed for group chats. Read `thread_user` as `chat_participants`